# Save polygon within shapefile as own shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I have a shapefile of multiple watersheds, and I want to extract one of them to save as its own shapefile. I have no clue which package or command to use.

Can someone point me to a function within GeoPandas or another Python package?

```
import geopandas


shed = geopandas.read_file('CA_HUC12.shp')
shed.head()
OBJECTID    TNMID   LoadDate    GNIS_ID AreaAcres   AreaSqKm    States         Geometry 
1       2012-10-15  0.0 21270.0 86.076712   CA  180300120503    Canoas Creek   POLYGON ((-120.1708092427523 36.07190695803973..
2       2012-10-15  0.0 32827.0 132.846273  CA  180600150201    Bear Creek     POLYGON ((-122.1102488777835 37.24771269698346...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the wonderful GeoPython tutorial [here](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson2-geopandas-basics.html). You can use slicing to get your new watershed: **new_shapefile.shp** as shown below

```
out = "C:/your_data_folder/new_shapefile.shp"
selection = shed[161:162] # where you watershed of interest is in row 161
selection.to_file(out)
```